# JSONObject и кирилица

Tags: android

Android. Создаю JSONObject записываю в значение кирилицу, в отладчике значение уже ромбы с вопросами. Как записать кирилицу?

String json = "{"alert": "Обновление!"}";
data = new JSONObject(json);

Answer (score 1):

Решил проблему, перевел написание кода android studio UTF-8.

Answer (score 0):

```
new String(data .getString("alert").getBytes("UTF-8"), "windows-1251");
```

Как то так